# Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel

Tags: asp.net

Hi i am getting this error when i am debugging the web application

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or
>   one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an
>   assembly manifest.

Kindly tell me the right solution

Comment: Are you targeting 4.0? Did the application start off as a 3.5 website/app?

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226429/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-identitymodel-version-4-0-0-0-culture).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same error about System.IdentityModel and the reason was that I used a **.Net Core 3.1** Console App to call into a **.Net Framework 4.7.2** project that invoked service call to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Organization service (StackTrace = "at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.ToOrganizationServiceProxy..).

It is compatibility issue, so I simply moved the console app to .Net Framework 4.7.2, then no issue any more.

Answer (score 0):

Check framework version of your project - as I know this assembly needs 4.0+
And if 1st is true - try to add this assembly to your references list manually