# Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am new to mvc. I just installed the Visual studio 15 and when i create a mvc project and run it without any modification. it gives me the above mentioned error. I did the same thing on another pc and it works but on my system it gives me the error. search for solutions but could not find any specific. so please guide me what to do.

Comment: Did you find a fix for that I am having similar problem with dotnet core

Answer (score 1):

*"Could not load file or assembly 'AAAAAAAAAA, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies."* is a common error. Try the following methods in order to fix this error:

***Method I:*** Add the following key to the  section in your web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" >    
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="AAAAAAAAAA, Version=4.0.0.0, 
          Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx" />
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

***Method II:*** If the problem is not solved, try to run this command on PM Console:

*Install-Package AAAAAAAAAA*

Hope this helps...

Comment: The message `Could not load file or assembly '...' or one of its dependencies` is quite common. Can you please [edit] your answer to explain what the config file change does and why it works. I.e., can you please generalize your answer.

Comment: It didn't work with method 1 and in method 2 it gives the below error.


Install-Package : Unable to find package 'System.IdentityModel'
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package System.IdentityModel
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Could you please try **Install-Package IdentityModel** on PM?